# Document management system using Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, document-management

I am currently working on different aspect Google App Engine and still in study phase and build some small apps and deployed it on cloud.  Recently when i was installing a command line to for cloud storage(i.e. gsUtil) I encountered versioning support on cloud storage and was able to retrieve old objects or deleted objects through gsUtil . So building a document management system on GAE is good idea with Google cloud storage or I should be using Google drive SDK ?

Please guide me on this problem .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely different products for completely different use cases.

Google Cloud Storage is a storage on cloud, no more abstractions. If you want to build a document management system from scratch, you can prefer it as the storage provider.

If you build an app on the top of Google Drive, you inherit a file system abstraction,  user management, a permissions model and etc. But you don't own the users, neither their drives. Additionally, Drive's quota management is fined tuned for "per-user" usage. Most people think creating a single Drive account and logically share it among their users on the application level will work. It's unlikely to scale due to the quota limitations.

Comment: Thank you @Burcu . My question is can I handle versioning through my java code like mention in this link (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) like listing all versions of an object , retrieving a specfic version of an object etc.

Comment: I think it's better to ask it to google-cloud-storage as a standalone question. I'm not familiar with their versioning system, I'm speaking on the behalf of Drive.

Comment: @user953131 please open a new thread if you have questions about versioning